# Assigning NSString value to a UI Label text

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I am trying to assign my NSString object's value to a UILabel.text property like this:

```
lblCalories.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _pickData[row]];
```

and yeah the value of _pickData[row] is all good - made sure that was the case but somehow lblCalories just appears as null.

Please help!

Comment: Is your UILabel's IBOutlet setup correctly or is it coded?

Comment: You need to connect the UILabel property to a UILabel in IB.

Comment: sorry solved - should have accessed it as _lblCalories.text - it worked.

Comment: @sr1972 If the value is a property please use `self.<name>` rather than `_<name>`. The former calls the setter/getter while the latter goes straight to the backing instance variable. Using nothing but the latter makes using properties in the first place utterly pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I believe this is your problem.

Your UILabel property should be setup like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblCalories;
```

Then you need to connect this to an actual UILabel in Interface Builder. After that you can set the text by using:

```
self.lblCalories.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.pickData[row]];
```

Also just a side note, it is really best practice to use `self.property` instead of `_property`